# Why behaviour from AppDelegate and via typhoon is different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, typhoon

i want to set style for status bar to:

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

if i'm doing it from AppDelegate directly - everything is ok, but via Typhoon - not.

1) That's working ok:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[self styleKit] apply];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

2) And that's not working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return YES;
}

-(void)initialize {
    [[self styleKit] apply];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

at second way i use typhoon like:

```
@implementation LAMainAssembly
-(AppDelegate *)appDelegate {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AppDelegate class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(window) with:[self mainWindow]];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(styleKit)];
        [definition performAfterInjections:@selector(initialize)];
    }];
}
@end
```

in both cases i use same advanced version of styling, where there is a:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because Typhoon starts it's initialization before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

I would recommend to avoid dependency on `Typhoon` initialization order and do any UI setup explicit after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method called (your first way)

Comment: but i also use performAfterInjection and in real application i call 'bootstrapper' that deallocs right after bootstrap. Like:

Comment: `performAfterInjection` will be called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` too. Because it's called right after injection, and whole injections process happens to AppDelegate just after it's created, while `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called after application launched and UI created